# indexing (querying) ndgrid output without actually constructing it

Tags: matlab, memory, multidimensional-array

Is there anyway to index a ndgrid output without actually constructing the output, because of memory issues? Suppose we need to construct *output* and ask for *i* th element

```
[output{1:n}] = ndgrid(1:k)  
[output{1}(i) ... output{n}(i)]
```

Is it possible to avoid the construction?

Comment: Sample input and expected output to explain it a bit further?

Comment: When you say `i^th` element, you do mean the linear index `i`, right? Because, each matrix from `output{1}` to `output{n}` is going to be multidimensional.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Right, with linear indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the function [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[o{1:n}] = ind2sub( ones(1,n)*k, ii );
```

The size of your ndgrid is `[k, k, ... k]` (`n` times) and you are trying to access the linear index `ii` into this `k^n` dimensional hyper-volume.

---

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: One interesting thing is that the reverse operation can be done using [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had worked this out, so I am posting a complete answer. Write the following function in an m-file:

```
function output=my_ndgrid(varargin)

in=nargin;
sz=zeros(1,in-1);
for i=1:in-1
    sz(i)=length(varargin{i});
end

ind=varargin{in};

[ndgrid_ind{1:length(sz)}] = ind2sub(sz,ind);

for i=1:length(sz)
    output{i}(ind)=varargin{i}(ndgrid_ind{i});
end

end
```

following command taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27010611/1586200) answer

`[ndgrid_ind{1:length(sz)}] = ind2sub(sz,ind);`

In the above function, you can pass as many arguments as you want, same as you would pass to `ndgrid`. Just the last argument has to be the index (in your case the `i^th` element, so the index will be `i`).

For example,

```
a=my_ndgrid(1:3:10,2:2:6,5:1:8,10); %asking for 10th element
```

It will be stored as `a{1}(10),...,a{3}(10)`, as you wanted.

You get `[4 6 5]` as the answer which matches by creating `ndgrid` manually.